# Error when checking model input: Found: <keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator... object> in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have batches of data in an iterator, here, using native Keras and nothing fancy:

`batches = gen.flow_from_directory(path, target_size=(224,224), class_mode=class_mode, shuffle=shuffle, batch_size=batch_size)` .

which appears fine:

`print batches:`

> keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x7f107c004210\

But now I've compiled and I'm ready to `fit`:

`model.compile(optimizer=Adam(1e-5), loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
                     metrics=['accuracy'])` .

`model.fit(batches, val_batches, nb_epoch=1)`

but I keep getting:

`Exception: Error when checking model input: data should be a Numpy array, or list/dict of Numpy arrays. Found: <keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x7f107c004210>...`

No Keras doesn't like that I'm using an iterator? Why can't I fit using an iterator? I thought that's the whole point -- don't eat up all your memory, instead use some kind of batch iterator.

Comment: you need to use fit_generator, not fit.

Answer (score 3):

`fit` method expects its input to be a Numpy array or list of Numpy array. You should use [`fit_generator`](https://keras.io/models/model/#methods) instead, which takes a generator as its argument.

```
model.fit_generator(generator=batches, 
                    validation_data=val_batches, 
                    nb_epoch=1)
```